# Python open CV2 code not working

Tags: python

i was trying to replicate python CV2 code to extract text from a image file, it runs without errors but i still cannot get any output.

Here is my code

```
>>> import cv2
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
/Users/upendrakumardevisetty/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:81: RuntimeWarning: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL
warnings.warn(str(v), RuntimeWarning)
>>> img = cv2.imread('road.png', 0)
>>> plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', interpolation='bicubic')
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage object at 0x1099c6150>
>>> plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
(([], <a list of 0 Text xticklabel objects>), ([], <a list of 0 Text yticklabel objects>))
>>> plt.show()
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: i tested your code, it works just fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You are exiting your program before you give it a chance to show. You should add one more line to your script after `plt.show()`:

```
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Then you can force the window to close by typing any key.

Comment: I tried adding the line but still i don't see any output. I have one question though. I am mostly interested in extracting the text from the image and i am wondering i am not doing it correct here. Right?